# Are Facebook canvas apps required to provide non-secure endpoints?

Tags: facebook, ssl, https, facebook-canvas

The Facebook documentation says that since October 1, 2011 canvas apps must provide access over HTTPS. Is the opposite true? Must canvas apps provide access over HTTP? I'd rather have my app accessible through HTTPS only. Will Facebook users using HTTP be able to use my app if I don't provide a non-secure endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only specify a secure URLK - they will not be.  They will be prompted with a layer asking them to enable secure browsing.  They will NOT be able to access you application.

Comment: Does this essentially mean that in order for them to use my app without enabling secure browsing, I must make my app insecure?

Comment: This is true.  If you specify both secure and non-secure URL's a Facebook user will see the content over whatever protocol they are using.  The opposite is also true - if there is only a secure URL users will be required to use secure browsing and your secure URL.